# How to implement a custom EdgeTreatment for a complex shape?

Tags: android, view, shapes, shadow, material-components-android

I need to create a view with a custom appearance, like the following: [custom shape with rounded zig-zagged border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nNG0.png).
Since there is a strong need of having shadows, I'd like to use a MaterialCardView to have the shadows and the correct feedback and behavior already in place.
So I was wondering if a shape like that (the yellow one and then white just mirroring) could be developed with a custom EdgeTreatment for the top edge, or if there are other ways to reach this design in an elegant manner.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I just tried with rect lines, obtaining the shape i would like to have but without any roundness.

```
class MaterialCustomCardShape(
    private val middlePoint: Float, //The value of view.width/2
    private val stepHeight: Float //The value of the groove
): EdgeTreatment() {
    override fun getEdgePath(
        length: Float,
        center: Float,
        interpolation: Float,
        shapePath: ShapePath,
    ) {
        shapePath.lineTo(middlePoint, 0f) // Going till the middle
        shapePath.lineTo(middlePoint, stepHeight) //Going down by stepHeight pixels
        shapePath.lineTo(length, stepHeight) //Reach the end of the view
```